# How to fetch data from a JSON file in aurelia framework?

Tags: aurelia

I'm trying to fetch data from external JSON file using [aurelia-fetch-client](https://aurelia.io/docs/plugins/http-services#aurelia-fetch-client) but it gives 404 not found error.

I have tried implementing the basic setup suggested by the official docs.

Here is my code:

```
import {HttpClient } from 'aurelia-fetch-client';

let httpClient = new HttpClient();
export class ChangeRequest {
constructor(){
  httpClient.fetch('sample.json')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res);
 }
}
}
```

I should get the result of the JSON data, but I'm getting the following error:

[image: error]

Here's my folder structure which was created using `aurelia-cli`

[image]

As you can see the `sample.json` is inside the `src` folder, and I have tried putting it inside the `src/Assets` folder but same result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given that you're using Webpack, you have two choices:

- Keep the file in the `src` directory and use a `require` statement to load it
- Move the file to the `static` folder and load it using `fetch`.

Here is a screenshot of an example with both:

[image: Screenshot showing using both require and fetch for loading a json file]

And the source code:

```
export class App {
  async attached() {
    const importedData = require('./in-src.json');

    const fetchedData = await fetch('in-static.json')
      .then(response => response.json());

    console.log('JSON loaded via import', importedData);
    console.log('JSON loaded via fetch', fetchedData);
  }
}
```

Finally, the console when the app is run:

[image]

Comment: Regarding putting this in the docs, this isn't really an Aurelia specific thing. This is a Webpack concept. Even understanding that you can't fetch files from your src directory is a Webpack concept moreso than an Aurelia concept.

Comment: Then why there are other generic syntax resides in docs which are unrelated to aurelia? Docs says to use aurelia-fetch-client plugin, but your solution didn't utilize it, then how am I supposed to put it in the static folder in the first place? Should have mentioned in the docs. Every other frameworks have explained loading from external json. Now I realize why this framework is not popular.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a wonderful place to get help with problems you are encountering as you develop new software. It is not a place for disparaging comments. You received free technical support from three Aurelia Core Team members both here and on GitHub (where you explicitly ignored the instructions in our Issue Template). The question you asked was not well formed, as it did not provide adequate information to answer your question (I had to read your comment to an answer to realize you are using Webpack with the Aurelia CLI)... (cont'd)\

Comment: (cont'd) After receiving free support, even though you ignored support instructions, you chose to disparage our documentation and the framework itself. A framework that has been provided to you at no cost, developed by volunteers.  Think about how entitled your comment sounds, and consider that comments like your's are the very type of comment that drives developers away from doing open source development. And next time, maybe think about not making a comment like that.

Answer (score 2):

The reason it gives you 404 is that the development web server does not have that file, as you can see where it tried to get the file from: `http://localhost:8080/sample.json`

What you can do is to make sure it goes to your dev server, probably by putting it in the same folder with your assets such as images. If you are using aurelia-cli, maybe you can put it into `dist` folder as well.

Comment: Putting it inside `dist` folder worked as expected, but if I do `au build --env prod` then whole dist folder is being replaced and json file is gone, maybe need to configure this in `webpack.config.js` so it will be copied automatically, I'll get back once it's done.